# Using SUBSTRING and STUFF together

Tags: sql-server, substring, rows

Using SQL Server 10.0 and 10.5

I'm trying to fetch multiple rows into one row and comma seperate them in a SELECT statement

If I do this:

```
SELECT STUFF(CAST(rating AS VARCHAR),1,0,',')
FROM product_reviews
WHERE product_id = 8995
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I get the desired result except for the leading comma.

So I change the first line to attempt to remove the leading comma like so:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(CAST(rating AS VARCHAR),1,0,','),2,999)
FROM product_reviews
WHERE product_id = 8995
FOR XML PATH('')
```

This removes all the commas.

Next I try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ratings,2,999)
FROM (SELECT STUFF(CAST(rating AS VARCHAR),1,0,',') AS ratings
      FROM product_reviews
      WHERE product_id = 8995
      FOR XML PATH('')) tmp
```

But that just gives me the error:

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'tmp'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ratings'.
```

I have used other names for column 1 with same error

I know I can create a procedure to do this, but that's not what I need here.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT
        ',',
        CAST(rating AS VARCHAR)
    FROM product_reviews
    WHERE product_id = 8995
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((
  SELECT STUFF(CAST(rating AS VARCHAR),1,0,',')
  FROM product_reviews
  WHERE product_id = 8995
  FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 999)
```

Comment: This comes up with the same error as before: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'str'

Comment: That works now - cheers.  I prefer the previous solution though as it doesn't depend on the result being less than 999 characters.  However, yours works properly when the CAST is removed.

Comment: Also, looking at the execution plan of both, they are exactly the same speed (at least in this small test)